# Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

In the following async await function I had return type of `Promise: <any>` but I wanted to correct that so I did the following:

```
export const getMarkets = async (): Promise<IGetMarketsRes> => {
  try {
    const nomicsUSD = prepHeaders('USD');
    const marketUSD = await nomicsUSD.get(exchangeMarketPrices);
    const nomicsUSDC = prepHeaders('USDC');
    const marketUSDC = await nomicsUSDC.get(exchangeMarketPrices);
    const nomicsUSDT = prepHeaders('USDT');
    const marketUSDT = await nomicsUSDT.get(exchangeMarketPrices);

    console.log('marketUSD', marketUSD);

    return {
      marketUSD: marketUSD.data,
      marketUSDC: marketUSDC.data,
      marketUSDT: marketUSDT.data
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

However that creates the error above.

[image]

Where `getMarkets` is called:

```
export const fetchMarketPrices = (asset: string) => (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch(actionGetMarketPrices);
  return getMarkets().then((res) => {
    const { marketUSD, marketUSDC, marketUSDT } = res;
    const combinedExchanges = marketUSD.concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT);
    const exchangesForAsset = combinedExchanges.filter((marketAsset: IMarketAsset) =>
      marketAsset.base === asset);
    return dispatch(actionSetMarketPrices(exchangesForAsset));
  });
}
```

**What is/are the proper Types for that** `Promise<>` **syntax?**

---

I also tried this which I expected to be the correct way, but got a missing return for Promise, but this is an async await function which is why the return is in the `try` statement:

`export const getMarkets = async (): Promise<IGetMarketsRes> => {`

[image]

Comment: so in case of error function will implicitly return `undefined`. How can it affect caller? Is not better just rethrow error after `console.log`? this way also you might moving `return` to be out of `try {} catch {}` so TS would be fine then

Comment: @skyboyer oh yeah, the function still works without the `try catch`, thanks for the tip! If you want to post go ahead and I'll accept. Otherwise I'll keep refactoring then post my fixed solution :)

Comment: Alternatively you could have declared a return type of `Promise<IGetMarketsRes | undefined>`, but it looks more like you don't really want to *handle* errors in that function.

Comment: @Bergi your solution allows me to keep the `try catch` want to post the answer?

Comment: @LeonGaban it allows you to keep the `try`/`catch` at the expense at having to explicitly check for the `undefined` result at every call site of `getMarkets()`, which isn't good style either.

Comment: @Bergi I guess the benefit is if some other error, like a `500` happens the catch will trigger at least.

Comment: @LeonGaban Don't you have a `try`/`catch` around the call, where you use the `IGetMarketsRes` value?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best solution would be to throw an error on the catch, instead of undefining the return type. The `undefined` type removes the whole point of using TypeScript otherwise.

Try this:

```js
export const getMarkets = async (): Promise<IGetMarketsRes> => {
  try {
     // Your code :)
  } catch (err) {
    // Throw error
    throw(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

### Solution to keep the try catch

```
export const getMarkets = async (): Promise<IGetMarketsRes | undefined> => {
  try {
    const nomicsUSD = prepHeaders('111');
    const marketUSD = await nomicsUSD.get(exchangeMarketPrices);
    const nomicsUSDC = prepHeaders('222');
    const marketUSDC = await nomicsUSDC.get(exchangeMarketPrices);
    const nomicsUSDT = prepHeaders('333');
    const marketUSDT = await nomicsUSDT.get(exchangeMarketPrices);

    const { data: dataUSD } = marketUSD;
    const { data: dataUSDC } = marketUSDC;
    const { data: dataUSDT } = marketUSDT;

    if (R.isEmpty(dataUSD) || R.isEmpty(dataUSDC) || R.isEmpty(dataUSDT)) {
      console.error('Market data unavailable');
    }

    return {
      marketUSD: marketUSD.data,
      marketUSDC: marketUSDC.data,
      marketUSDT: marketUSDT.data
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

### A Much better DRY example

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213909/get-an-array-of-currency-exchange-prices-based-on-asset

```
export const fetchMarket = async (currency: string): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    const request = prepHeaders(currency);
    const response =  await request.get(EXCHANGE_MARKET_PRICES);
    if (!response) {
      throw new Error('USD Markets unavailable.');
    }
    return response.data;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

// GET Market prices
// http://docs.nomics.com/#operation/getMarkets
export const getMarkets = async (): Promise<IGetMarketsRes | undefined> => {
  try {
    const markets: IMarketRes = {};

    for (let currency of BASE_CURRENCIES) {
      const key = 'market' + currency;
      markets[key] = await fetchMarket(currency);
    }

    return {
      marketUSD: markets['marketUSD'],
      marketUSDC: markets['marketUSDC'],
      marketUSDT: markets['marketUSDT'],
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

---

And the call from the actions file:

```
// Fetch USD, USDC & USDT markets to filter out Exchange List.
export const fetchMarketPrices = (asset: string) => (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch(actionGetMarketPrices);
  return getMarkets().then((res) => {
    if (res) {
      const exchangesForAsset = combineExchangeData(asset, res);
      return dispatch(actionSetMarketPrices(exchangesForAsset));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why rethrow error is not the accepted answer? If you put `undefined` type you can get `TS7030: Not all code paths return a value` in some situations.

Answer (score 7):

In case of an error, your code implicitly returns `undefined` because you catch the `error` without rethrowing it.

I guess that your `tsconfig.json` file has `noImplicitReturns` set to `true`. If you change it to `false`, the compiler error will not show up anymore. However, I suggest to keep `noImplicitReturns` set to `true` and to re-throw the error in your `catch` clause.

You can also return a default `IGetMarketsRes` in the `catch` block if it works with your application logic. I made a video which shows you the different possibilities to handle [**error TS2366**](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2366): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N_P-l5Kukk&t=363s