# Error: "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React-Select drop down and doing an async call to get data from an API.

Here is my type:

```
type Person = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};
```

Here is my promise for the data API:

```
const fetchDropDown = async () : Promise<Array<Person>>  => {
  try {
  const stuff = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]);
  const records = stuff.value;
  const options = records?.map<Person>(d  => ({
    "value": d.name,
    "label": d.name
  }));
    console.log(options)
    return options as Person[] 
    
     
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is my React component:

```
<div>
       <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          defaultOptions
          loadOptions={fetchDropDown}
        />
```

At the top of the promise on this line :

```
const fetchDropDown = async () : Promise<Array<Person>>  => {
```

I am getting the error:

```
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'
```

How can I get this final bit working so in the drop down I can see my rows from the API?

So to get the component to drop down with the rows, I need it to be in a value/label pair  and that's why I have gone with the .map command.

Comment: You don't return anything when there is an error. Instead you throw an error. You might want to return the error instead and change up your API so that the caller can decide what to do with the error.

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate: [Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812453/function-lacks-ending-return-statement-and-return-type-does-not-include-undefin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some similar issues and this knew to help.
What happens is you specified output and try catch goes to error and returns something else.

```
const fetchDropDown = async () : Promise<Array<Person>>  => {


try {
  const stuff = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]);
  const records = stuff.value;
  const options = records?.map<Person>(d  => ({
    "value": d.name,
    "label": d.name
  }));
    console.log(options)
    
     
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw(error)
      }
    }
   return options as Person[] 
  }
```

Comment: Hi this is really helpful and it is almost working but what does this in the react : vendors~main.chunk.js:91910 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'options' in

Comment: I mean message means by itself you are using in operator somewhere you cannot. I don't see it in this code so you have error somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you have an un-accounted for scenario.

There are 3 possible scenarios here:

- If we **don't** end up in the catch block the function returns `options as Person[]` ***-> this is ok***
- If we **do** end up in the catch block **and** `error === true` we throw and error ***-> this is ok***
- If we **do** end up in the catch block **and** `error === false` we do nothing ***-> this is not ok***

Meaning that you should also account for the 3rd scenario, and that's what the error is telling you.
We can either return a value or throw an error, either way, needs to be handled.